# SSIS Variable Cannot Be Found in List of Variables

Tags: ssis

I have an SSIS task that has run fine for at least the past 2 years. IT moved the tasks to a new server and now it is throwing a "The variable name "User::obEmailBody" could not be found in the list of variables" error.

I copied the task back to my desktop and it ran fine. It only fails on the server. I've verified the variable is there and is getting populated in my test environment (local desktop). I am at a loss why it fails on the server. The variable is a system.object.

Is there a setting on the server that would prevent the creation of a system.object variable?

Comment: No, there is no server setting that will affect the creation of a variable. Edit your question to show some of the expressions, if they exist, variables, configuration of the email task, etc

Comment: In the server, does the variable exists???? To check if the variable exists in the Serve's SSIS, please go to SSIS -> Variable, it will display a list of variables...

Comment: The variable is being used to hold a Recordset Destination. I populate it in a dataflow task and then read it in a different dataflow task using a Foreach ADO Enumerator.

Comment: Yes, the variable exists. As I indicated it runs fine locally but only fails on the server.

Comment: Have you tried deleting the package and re-importing it to the server?   maybe it got corrupted.

Comment: Check if there are any package configurations in place, like xml file or Environment variables etc,

Comment: I ended up deleting the Recordset Destination task and recreating. I don't know why that one task got corrupted. It is working again.

Answer (score 1):

I have recently experienced this type of issue with a fairly simple and  straightforward package which read the data from an excel spreadsheet, cleaned the data the passed the data to SQL stored procedures, which needed to run on a nightly basis.  This package was executed as a SQL job within a SQL clustered environment.  After going to production, we discovered that one of the nodes worked without issues while the other node gave us the error "the variable name 'User::oInternalUser' could not be found in the list of variables". The only difference in these nodes were that the SSIS components were installed after the servers were spun up. After several hours of troubleshooting this issue, we decided to open a ticket with Microsoft.  After nearly 4 hours of troubleshooting with two resources, we were given the following recommendations.

- Upgrade SQL 2012 to service pack 3. This should repair any corruptions within SSIS components.
- Install the 64-bit version of the Ace drive and execute package in 64-bit mode.
- Perform a Time Travel Trace. I was cautioned about the performance hit that would occur during this process although it sounded promising, the extent of the performance hit was unknown and not a good idea to do on a production environment.

The solution that we went with was to rebuild the server with all the SSIS components and install 64-bit version of the ACE driver to run the package in 64-bit mode. This has resolved our issues. We made a copy of the server and these two rebuilt servers now encompass our cluster.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up deleting the Recordset Destination task and recreating.